# Most efficient way to join fields in a dynamic table structure

Tags: sql, t-sql

We have three tables storing document information that I'll call table A, B, and C.  Table A stores the main fields for said documents (such as the file name and size and other general information).  In order to dynamically add new fields, we use Table B to store a list of new fields and their data types(determined by an enumeration), and Table C to store the values for those fields.

```
Table A
ID   - PK int
FieldX...
FieldY...
FieldZ...

Table B
Id   - PK int
Name - nvarchar(max)
Type - int

Table C
Id    - PK int
AId   - FK to table A int
BId   - FK to table B int
Value - nvarchar(max)
```

What we want to do as efficiently as possible is to pull the values from table C as an additional column in a query from table A.  Right now here is how I'm doing it for each extra field in Table B.

```
select (select c.value 
        from B b, C c
        where c.AId = a.Id 
        and c.Bid = b.Id
        and b.Name = 'Dynamic Field Name') As 'Dynamic Field Name'
From A a
```

We have a database with Table A filled with 36000 rows.  For each additional dynamic field that is added to the query, its adding about 4 seconds to the total time to finish the query, making a query that contains 10 dynamic fields take at least 40 seconds.  Realistically, we want any query to finish in under 10.  Is there any way to write this more efficiently?

Comment: how do you pass the dynamic field names to `b.Name`? Through a comma delimited list, hard coded or many many sp arguments?

Answer (score 0):

First of all your query may give you errors because you have not defined C.(A+B) as unique. If there are multiple values per `A+B` combination in C, it causes the subquery to fail with

```
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value.
```

Assuming it is unique, then you should be safe to just LEFT JOIN them together to make use of SET-based operations.

```
select a.*,
       c1.value [Dynamic Field Name 1],
       c2.value [Dynamic Field Name 2]
From A a
JOIN B b1 on b1.Name = 'Dynamic Field Name1'
LEFT JOIN C c1 on c1.AId = a.Id and c.Bid = b1.Id
JOIN B b2 on b2.Name = 'Dynamic Field Name2'
LEFT JOIN C c2 on c2.AId = a.Id and c2.Bid = b2.Id
```

Using a subquery at the SELECT level forces each record, and each dynamic field to execute as a mini-select = very slow.

Comment: To clarify, yes the values are unique and you will never have subqueries returning more than one value.  This method was actually about 100 times slower than the other way I was running the queries.  I guess joining tables is much more expensive than a sub select?

Comment: Depends on what indexes you have set up. Do you have one on `B.name`? If not, create it. Your query will run faster if there are very few dynamic values because it will resolve the link A<->C first and find little to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a query like this would work as well:

```
select a.id
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN b.Name = 'Dynamic Field Name' THEN c.value END) As Dynamic_Field_Name
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN b.Name = 'Dynamic Field Name 2' THEN c.value END) As Dynamic_Field_Name2
  from A a,  B b, C c
  where c.AId = a.Id 
    and c.Bid = b.Id
    and b.Name IN ('Dynamic Field Name', 'Dynamic Field Name 2')
  group by a.id
```

Same idea, you only want to make one pass through the table, rather than a lookup for each row. The aggregate is to compress the sparse matrix into a single row (ie there will only by one dynamic field value in a row, each row having a different column with a value). Don't know how it would perform though.

Comment: You need left joins otherwise you will lose records where the dynamic fields are empty

Comment: @Richardakacyberkiwi Agreed. This assumes that if the dynamic fields are listed in the "in" clause, they actually exist with values.